# Excel save relative formula for re-use

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to go through a sheet, filtering on a series of fields and running a formula against the resulting columns.
However, typing the formula each time is slow and annoying.

How can I save the formula I'm using to simply reuse, like this: `=MY_FORM`

```
First: =SUBTOTAL(9,Q1:Q1532)

Second: =((O1569:Q1569)/3)
```

Comment: You could set up a macro, or a custom function - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-Custom-Functions-in-Excel-2007-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f

Comment: So you need to filter by each and get those results? Why not try a pivot table!

Comment: @Raystafarian. Physically kicked myself. You're correct, Sir